# Neat 2.1.0 - Automatic Rows / Omega feature removal

Tags: neat

In previous versions of neat, it was possible to achieve "automatic rows" using @include omega();

From what I can see, this feature has been removed in the latest version of Neat?

Currently, I'm having to create an additional div to act as a clearfix to resolve this issue, for example;

```
.row {
  @include grid-container;
}
```

I just wanted to confirm whether there are any better ways to achieve automatic rows now that the omega feature has been removed?

Answer (score 0):

Use the neat-omega extension. You can find it at https://github.com/kgcreative/neat-omega

> The Omega family is a group of mixins that accomplish several supplemental goals within the Bourbon-Neat framework.